# $Z\pi \cong Z\oplus Z$ and so $P \cong Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology, projective-module, group-rings

If $\pi = Z$, then the augmentation ideal $P$ is projective  and $0 \to P \to Z\pi \to Z \to 0$ is a projective resolution.

Here we know that $P$ has basis $\mathbb{Z}-$ ${0}$ Then how to show that it is projective?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: By $\mathbb Z\pi$ you mean the group ring ?  If so, what makes you think that ?

Comment: Hi! I've made some changes. But still not quite clear how it is projective. Would you mind shedding some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the following exercise : as a $\mathbb Z\pi$-module, $P$ is freely generated by $g-1$, where $g$ is a generator for $\pi$.

What's true regardless of the group $\pi$ is that for any system of generators $g_1,...,g_n$ of $\pi$, $g_1-1,...,g_n-1$ generate $P$, you can try to prove that as well.

The point will then be that in this specific case, $g-1$ is a free generator of the ideal

(Maybe it's easier to see if you know that $\mathbb Z\pi \cong \mathbb Z[t,t^{-1}]$ )

Comment: Hi, do you mean P is a principal ideal? Thx!

Comment: In this case, yes- but also (this is the "freely" part) that $g-1$ is not a zero divisor

Comment: I've been confused by "basis" and "generators". I'm aware that $g_1 - 1$, ... $g_n -1$ is a basis for the free abelian group P. But I haven't been able to figure out how P as an ideal of the group ring is generated by one element of the basis (if this is what you mean.) thx!

Comment: It's not true that it's a basis for the free abelian group $P$. It's true that they generate $P$ as a (two-sided) ideal.